# Can ZigBee API and ZigBee AT modules work together in the same network?

Tags: api, at-command, arduino-uno, zigbee

I'm currently trying to make 3 arduinos talking to each other with ZigBee, and it's kinda working.
But I currently use AT mode on the Bees and it's a little bit harsh when I have to switch the destination address in the Coordinator of the network (1 Coordinator and 2 Routers)

Can I put the Coordinator in API mode (to make it easier to switch addresses with xbee-api for Arduino) but still be able to communicate with the AT routers and be able to send/receive data from them?

Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely, and it's common to set up a network like that.  You can have AT routers connected to "dumb" hosts that just send streams of serial data, and an API coordinator that receives from multiple routers, identifying the source of each message using the headers of the API frames, and able to send unicast messages back to individual routers or broadcast messages to all routers.

Make use of the 0x10 Transmit Request API frame to send from the coordinator to the routers.  You'll receive either 0x90 or 0x91 frames (depending on the setting of `ATAO`).